# Multithreading with variables unique to each thread

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, scope

I'm trying to implement a multi-threaded solution to a problem that requires something like the following

- I create 'n' threads
- I have an array of 'n - 1' size
- Each thread should only access its according element of the array (i.e thread 0 should affect only element 0 of the array, thread 1 should only affect element 1, and so on.)
- each thread will execute the same function that references the array by index 'k'

how can I change 'k' each time a thread is created in order to have it start at 0, and end at 'n - 1' such that each thread will only access its assigned array element?

Comment: When you say "n - 1" size, do you mean size n index from 0 to n - 1?

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't specified which compiler, or platform, so it's hard to give an example that solves your problem.  I've given my point to @andrew-henle as pthread is pretty common but not universal.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for pointing out this question isn't limited to POSIX.  I had my POSIX blinders on, apparently.... :-)

Comment: Every thread library I've worked with works in pretty much the same manner. They allow a pointer parameter upon thread creation, which will get passed to the thread callback.

Comment: @Lundin I guess someone should write an answer for the ISO C11 thread specification... although testing said answer might prove difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (on POSIX platforms...) and is an implementation of the method @Some Programmer Dude mentioned in his answer.  It should be portable and standard-compliant, as long as the implementation provides `intptr_t` as a type (it's optional):

```
void *start_func( void *arg )
{
    int myID = ( intptr_t ) arg;
       .
       .
       .
    return( NULL );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
       .
       .
       .
    pthread_t tid[ n ];
    for ( int k = 0; k < n; i++ )
    {
        pthread_create( &tid[ k ], NULL, start_func, ( void * )( intptr_t ) k );
    }
       .
       .
       .
    return( 0 );
}
```

You'd need to be careful on any architecture where `sizeof( int )` is greater than `sizeof( intptr_t )` *and* your loop values would overflow an `intptr_t`, but as far as I know such architectures simply do not exist.

Comment: What's the point of this though, even if portable? "It is possible to do obscure things so we must do it" is not a sound rationale. Just pass a pointer, as is the intention of the thread API. Scope issues is not a valid rationale either, since any local variable declared in main() would have the same scope as your `pthread_t` handles. If those go out of scope, then bad things will happen.

Comment: In this case, I have to agree with @Lundin, (strange, I know,  but he's right:).

Comment: @Lundin The point is it's simple, concise, understandable, portable, standard-compliant, and works without any constraints or complications.  No scope problems, no possible scalability issues with dynamic memory allocation.  One could always write the caller and the start function in assembler, where bits are just bits to be used as desired instead of pointers or integers.  There are always platform-specific concerns in C code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The POSIX standard kind of states that the parameter of pthread_create should be a pointer to an allocated object. To abusing this pointer and passing a value through it and then call it standard compliant is a stretch. To write code that passes a pointer to a variable would be simpler and more understandable. In fact, the very reason why we are having this debate is why I don't understand the logic behind "we can do obscure things so we must do it". There is no performance benefit or anything with your method.

Comment: I can see an obvious maintenance issue though: suppose someone maintaining the code must change the type of the variable. Then they have to rewrite the code.

Comment: ^^^^^ adding extra fields to a struct/object is easy - just add it and rebuild, it's almost sure to work just as well as before.  Messing with the casting is much less flexible:(

Comment: In fact, there's this hack-ish but safe trick where you can append trailing objects to a struct. Sometimes used in API hacking such as when you have a defined callback with a given parameter format and want to add more parameters. Suppose the API expects `struct stuff`. You then create a `struct stuff_ex { struct stuff; extra_things; }`, give the API the first member of your struct, then have the callback grab the things you sneaked in at the end.

Comment: @Lundin *give the API the first member of your struct, then have the callback grab the things you sneaked in at the end.* :-o And you're criticizing my suggested use of casting an `int` to a `void *` through `intptr_t`?   ;-)

Comment: Rather, I have worked _with_ Microsoft API:s :) But the form of hack I describe is also a common way to implement polymorphism in C, so it isn't unheard of. And it is safe in terms of strict aliasing.

Comment: `( void * )( intptr_t ) k` may be an alignment violation in ISO C (IDK whether POSIX defines this)

Answer (score 1):

Let me emphasize that the accepted answer by Andrew Henle is perfectly fine and will work in every single C environment I have ever used even though he is technically incorrect to say it is portable and standards compliant.

I think I'd prefer either of the two following solutions

1. Pass a direct pointer to the element

   ```
   typedef /* whatever */ } MyType;
   MyType* array;
   int main(int argc, char*argv[])
   {
       // find out what n is
       array = calloc(n, sizeof *array);
       // some stuff including filling in array
       pthread_t tid[n];
       for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
       {
           pthread_create( &tid[k], NULL, startFunc, &array[k]);
       }
       // do stuff including wait for the threads to finish
   }

   void startFunc(void* param)
   {
       MyType* myObject = (MyType*)param;
       // Do stuff directly on myObject
       // or if you *really* need to recover k:
       ptrdiff_t k = myObject - array;
   }
   ```

   I like this solution because the thread does not need to know anything about the context of the single piece of data it is working on.
2. Create a context type to pass to the thread start function and put everything you need in it.

   ```
   typedef /* whatever */ } MyType;
   MyType* array;
   struct ThreadContext
   {
       pthread_t tid;
       int k;
       MyType *array;
       size_t arraySize;
   }

   int main(int argc, char*argv[])
   {
       // find out what n is
       array = calloc(n, sizeof *array);
       // some stuff including filling in the array
       struct Context* contexts = calloc(n, sizeof *contexts);
       for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
       {
           contexts[k].array = array;
           contexts[k].arraySize = n;
           contexts[k].k = k;
           pthread_create( &(contexts[k].tid), NULL, startFunc, &contexts[k]);
       }
       // do stuff including wait for the threads to finish
   }

   void startFunc(void* param)
   {
       struct Context* context= (struct Context*)param;
       doSomethingWithArrayObject(context->array, context->k);
   }
   ```

   This is more like the normal way of passign contextual data to a callback function. You can put everything you need in the thread in the Context struct instead of relying on globals.

Answer (score 0):

While it is somewhat discouraged, you *can* pass the *value* of `k` to the thread function with some casting back and forth.

Or you can allocate an `unsigned int` dynamically (one per thread) to store the value of `k` and pass that pointer to the thread function (which copies it and then free the allocated memory). This is safe and portable.

Comment: I'm not sure why passing an integer value as a `void *` should be discouraged.  `intptr_t` is portable.  `pthread_create( &tid[ i ], NULL, start_func, ( void * )( intptr_t ) i );` for passing a loop counter to `start_func( void *arg )` is perfectly fine.  `int myId = ( intptr_t ) arg;` will retrieve the `int` value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Normally I would really discourage such usage, but for threads I usually make this an exception to the rule. Other people might be more hard-line about it though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Technically `intptr_t` is optional. An implementation does not have to define it. It's also not guaranteed that casting an arbitrary `intptr_t` gives a valid or well defined pointer, only that casting a pointer (to void) to `intprtr_t` and back again will compare equal to the original pointer. Of course, in real life, with most modern architectures, we all know, it will work.

Comment: @JeremyP Doesn't that imply that for the casting to not work, that would mean converting an `int` to `intptr_t` would be irreversible.  Given the definition of `intptr_t`, I don't see how that could be possible, but I think I agree that's it's not *precluded* by the standard.  Seems like a good language-lawyer question.

Comment: @AndrewHenle No my point was that not every possible value of an `intptr_t` needs to be a valid pointer, only values that were derived by casting a pointer to intptr_t.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

- Allocate the variable in the caller that creates the thread.
- Pass a pointer to the variable as parameter to the thread upon creation.
- Inside the thread callback, cast the pointer back to the correct pointer type.
- De-reference the pointer and read the contents.

This approach is re-entrant, given that each thread gets its own variable.

Comment: Note:  by 'Allocate', I assume you mean 'mallocate':)    Also note that the created thread should free the passed pointer before exiting.  Other bodges, like using an array of parameter structs, are just messy, inflexible and may introduce lifetime problems.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit "mallocate" isn't a word. There's also no reason why you can't allocate the variable on the stack as long as the main thread doesn't exit the scope in which it is allocated before the threads have completed.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit No, I don't mean that. As long as the variable does not turn invalid during the execution of the thread, it doesn't matter how it is allocated. The main thread which creates all the other threads should be the one freeing them, so there is no reason why such a variable would go out of scope even if it is local to the caller. The key here is to actually know what you are doing. Allocating dynamically in the caller and freeing in the thread is just bad program design - that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: 'Allocating dynamically in the caller and freeing in the thread is just bad program design' - we may have to agree to differ in this case.  The other approaches apply unnecessary constraints, (maybe the number of threads to be created is unknown at design time or varies at runtime..), introduce the lifetime risks you describe and adds unnecessary and avoidable scope to data that belongs to the created thread and only to that thread.  'The main thread which creates all the other threads should be the one freeing them' is another avoidable constraint: assumes the 'main thread' is the creator..

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Dynamic allocation also has scalability issues.

Comment: @AndrewHenle well, you might consider that is some cases. Usually, the stack allocation required by a new thread dwarfs the size of any struct that might be allocated to transfer config/startup info to the new thread, rendering that allocation size irrelevant.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit And in general, the allocation of that small `struct` results in the same locking overhead as allocating the thread's stack does.  The allocation and the necessary freeing itself creates the overhead, and it's completely avoidable in the case of passing a simple `int` value to a thread.  Scalability is *hard* and every use of dynamic memory allocation limits it.

Comment: @"maybe the number of threads to be created is unknown at design time or varies at runtime" So you'd then use an array of thread arguments, which in itself is either allocated as a VLA or dynamically. And freed by the code that allocated it, not by some thread callback. It all boils down to this: In a sane program design, your thread handles and thread arguments exist in the same program module, with the same scope. If you worry about scope of the arguments, you must also worry about the scope of the thread handle. So this is not even an issue.

Comment: Example:  consider thread that waits on a queue for tasks.  If you want to terminate it, would you prefer to a) queue up a malloced termination-request task and then carry on, forgetting about the thread completely, knowing it will finish off all earlier tasks and free them as required, then free both the last termination message and the queue, or b) queue up a stack based termination struct, join with the thread and hope that it terminates soon so you can do more stuff?

Comment: 'not by some thread callback' - why would a callback be required?  free() does not need any callback.  Nor does a C++ or other OOP destructor, in general.

Comment: 'worry about the scope of the thread handle' - why would I worry about that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle 'ame locking overhead' - if you're even remotely worried about the lock overhead of a malloc, you should not be starting a new thread:)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit The example you mention is, again, caused by poor program design. Why was the termination tasks/variables not passed to the thread upon creation? Why was it given different scope/storage duration than the thread handle? "'worry about the scope of the thread handle' - why would I worry about that?" Because when you call pthread_join, you kind of want this handle to be valid. If it has gone out of scope, your program will halt and catch fire. If it has not, then why do you worry that the thread arguments have done so?

Comment: 'Because when you call pthread_join' - oh, I don't ever do that unless absolutely unavoidable:)  Pool and/or app-lifetime threads usually don't need expicit termination.  Continual create/terminate/destroy threads, maintaining data that really belongs to other threads, and other such micro-management, are one of the main reasons that multithreading causes so many problems and is seen as 'difficult', 'error-prone' and a 'black art' :(

Comment: @Lundin *So you'd then use an array of thread arguments, which in itself is either allocated as a VLA or dynamically. And freed by the code that allocated it, not by some thread callback.* That requires that the threads started communicate somehow to the parent thread that it's safe to either free the array or allow it to go out of scope.  The thread handle itself doesn't matter to the created thread, so it can go out of scope/be freed the moment `pthread_create()` returns.  The only concern would be leaking the thread ID - admittedly a concern, but that would have no impact on the new thread.